# Loading a certificate as embedded resource in an assembly

Tags: c#, azure, certificate, embedded-resource, x509certificate2

I have added a PFX file as an embedded resource in an assembly to use the certificate to sign a JWT token. I load the pfx as stream and read all the bytes and using X509Certificate2 to load the private key

> public X509Certificate2(byte[] rawData, string password)

Works fine on dev machine in both Debug/Release, but when deployed to azure apps ervice or a build machine i am seeing "Bad data" error.

Any help greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Since I can't seem to read my .pfx file from my embedded resources, could you post your code on how to do this? If necessary, I could ask a SO question

Comment: Never mind, got it working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you’d like to access certificate from app on Azure App Service web app, you can upload your certificate to the certificates collection in Azure Websites and consume it in your web application from your site’s personal certificate store.

**Upload a certificate**

[image]
**Adding an app setting named WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES with its value set to the thumbprint of the certificate**

[image]

**Consuming certificate in application**

```
X509Certificate2 retVal = null;

X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, false);

if (certCollection.Count > 0)
{
    retVal = certCollection[0];
}

certStore.Close();
```

For detailed information, please check: [Using Certificates in Azure Websites Applications](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/using-certificates-in-azure-websites-applications/)

Comment: Thank you!, yes i had missed this important step